# Consul.IO - Why does Consul Cluster need at least a quorum of server nodes to be active

Tags: consul, raft

I spent a little bit time to study about Consul. I had read about Consensus Protocol. I saw that if Consul cluster want to be available, it needs a quorum of servers node to elect leader. I wonder that when consul cluster has less than a quorum of nodes running, why does it not use the remain running nodes instead? 
Can anyone answer for me? Thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quorum is required to ensure that you'll never have inconsistent results. Otherwise a cluster of eight nodes `(A B C D E F G H)` might have a networking fail and become partitioned into two clusters `(A B C D) (E F G H)`. Those two clusters then make two separate decisions that are incompatible (say update the same property of some configuration). When the partition is healed there's no way to merge the two changes.

If a quorum is required then you know that any quorum has at least one copy of every decision made; thus any conflicts will be spotted by at least one node and disallowed.

Comment: I got your idea, but one thing I am still confused is the high availability of consul cluster. Why it needs at least a number of quorum to enable electing new leader?

Comment: Quorums are used to ensure only one side of a partition can make a decision (in other words elect a leader). If the cluster were to allow fewer than a quorum of nodes to make a decision then it would be possible for two sides to make a decision. For example, if three nodes of an eight node cluster were allowed to decide who the leader is, it would be possible for three to elect one leader and a different three to elect another. Requiring a quorum to make a decision on who the leader is ensures that only one side could have made that decision since only one side can have a majority.

Comment: @kuujo I have one more question about Leader Replication, why leader attempt to replicate data to a quorum of followers. Can you answer me ?